# How do I simplify this python if/elif statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm making a simple rock paper scissors game, and part of the code asks for the user to input at the end if they want to choose to continue to play the game or not, which then breaks out of a while loop or repeats. But the code feels a bit lengthy. Is there any way to make this more efficient?

```
 reset_answer = ["YES", "NO", "no", "yes", "y", "n"]
reset_answer_correct = None
while reset_answer_correct not in reset_answer:
    reset_answer_correct = input("That was fun! would you like to play again? Yes or no: ")
if reset_answer_correct == "YES" or reset_answer_correct == "yes" or reset_answer_correct == "y":
    continue
elif reset_answer_correct == "NO" or reset_answer_correct == "no" or reset_answer_correct == "n":
    print("Thanks for playing!")
    break
```

Comment: `if reset_answer_correct.lower() in ('yes', 'y')`

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do that. For example you can use regexps:

```py
import re

positive_answer = r"y(?:es)?"
negative_answer = r"no?"

def wanna_continue():
  while True:
    answer = input('That was fun! would you like to play again? Yes or no: ')
    if re.fullmatch(positive_answer, answer, re.I):
      return True
    if re.fullmatch(negative_answer, answer, re.I):
      return False

...

if wanna_continue():
  continue
else:
  print("Thanks for playing!")
  break
```

Comment: Adding to this - if you have unchanging regular expressions you can compile them for better performance when matching them.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Playsible you could do something like this

```py
action=None
exit_options = ["NO", "no","n"]
continue_options = ["Yes", "yes", "y"]
while action not in exit_options:
    action = input("Would you like to play? Yes or no: ")
    if action not in exit_options+continue_options:
        print("Invalid option")
print("Thank you for playing")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert answers to lowercase and write something like:

```py
NO_ANSWERS = ["no", "n"]

answer = None
while answer not in ["yes", "y"] + NO_ANSWERS:
    answer = (
        input("That was fun! would you like to play again? Yes or no: ").strip().lower()
    )

if answer in NO_ANSWERS:
    print("Thanks for playing!")
    break
continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change element order and use with slicing

```
reset_answer = ["YES", "yes", "y", "NO", "no", "n"]
reset_answer_correct = None
while reset_answer_correct not in reset_answer:
    reset_answer_correct = input("That was fun! would you like to play again? Yes or no: ")
    if reset_answer_correct in reset_answer[3:]:
        print("Thanks for playing!")
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of using

if reset_answer_correct == "YES" or reset_answer_correct == "yes" or reset_answer_correct == "y":
continue

use
if reset_answer_correct in reset_answer:
continue

Comment: Any non empty string is true in the if statement, which is completely different from the purpose of OP...

Comment: please use code fencing to show code as such